# Do custom metadata types count against the custom object limit?

Tags: custom-metadata

I couldn't find any information on this doing a search.  I know that custom **settings** count against the custom object limit, but wasn't sure about custom metadata types.  This is important as we can only have 20 custom objects in our org.

Comment: As long as it's not documented (as in case of custom settings), I would think its not counted towards that limit. A good way to confirm this will be to reach out to support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think they count against your custom object limits. Custom metadata types have their own limits for your organization.

Custom metadata types per organization: **100** This number includes all types developed in the organization and installed from managed and unmanaged packages.

> **NOTE:** Custom metadata records in certified managed packages that you’ve
>   installed don’t count toward your organization’s allotment. However,
>   custom metadata records that you create do count toward it. This rule
>   applies regardless of whether you create records in your own custom
>   metadata type or in a type from a certified managed package.

Please refer this article for more information on limits.
[Custom metadata types limits and considerations](https://support.salesforce.com/articleView?id=custommetadatatypes_limits.htm&type=5)